# Ugly Barchart with ggplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want to visualize survey data. The individual countries should be on the x-axis and the percentage share of contributions to the survey on the y-axis. I have created a data frame with the values and want to visualize them in a basic bar chart. But I keep on getting this ugly blob over and over again.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?
[this is how the workspace looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QolU.jpg)

My code:

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x="Country", y="Percentage share")) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

where df1 is the dataframe created from the Excel-file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For us to help you, we would need a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Remove the quotes from around `"Country"` and `"Percentage share"`. However, you need backticks around `Percentage share` since there is a space in the name, so you probably need ```aes(x = Country, y = `Percentage share`)```

Comment: Run the code `dput(df1)` and then paste the code it spits out from R into your question. It will make it easier for people to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Greetings and welcome to SO! You didn't provide your data or say specifically what you wanted from your bar, so it is difficult to help, but I have tried to simulate the data in your screenshot as best as possible. In the future, please use the `dput` from your data so its easier/faster for people to give you answers. First, your data:

```
#### Create Data ####
df <- data.frame(countries = c("Germany",
                               "Italy",
                               "France",
                               "Spain",
                               "Belgium",
                               "Netherlands",
                               "Austria",
                               "Poland"),
                 share = c(27.3,
                           23.5,
                           15.3,
                           8.8,
                           3.9,
                           3.8,
                           2.6,
                           1.2))
```

Then if we run the `tidyverse` and the following code, we can get a better looking bar graph using `geom_col`, which uses a simple x and y arrangement of the percentage by categorical variables here. I have flipped the plot with `coord_flip` because you likely have many countries listed so this will look better than simply plotting it as is. I also gave it labels with `labs` and colored the bars:

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Plot ####
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=countries,
             y=share))+
  geom_col(fill = "steelblue")+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(y="Percentage Share",
       x="Countries",
       title = "Percentage Share by Country")
```

Which gives you this:

[image]

For a bit more information, you can also add `geom_text` so there is a visual representation of the values:

```
#### Plot ####
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=countries,
             y=share))+
  geom_col(fill = "steelblue")+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(y="Percentage Share",
       x="Countries",
       title = "Percentage Share by Country")+
  geom_text(aes(label=share,
                hjust=-.2))
```

[image]

If you would like to customize more,  [there are a ton of options available.](http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html)